# Как создавать доп. страницы для плагина WP

Tags: php, wordpress

Я создаю плагин для WP, и мне нужна страница моего плагина, которая не будет отображаться в меню админ-панели.
Кто-нибудь знает, как добавить страницу для плагина?

Comment: Где страница - в админке или на фронте?

Comment: Страница в админке

Comment: Нужна страница в админке которая не будет отображаться.. Это как вообще? Где логика?

Comment: Она не будет отображаться в меню, то есть её не зарегистрируешь с помощью add_menu_page и add_submenu_page, но сама страница может быть показана, например, при нажатие кнопки в форме на эту страницу можно будет перейти

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если поставить `parent_slug` в `null`, то страница не будет показана в меню.

```
    // This submenu is HIDDEN.
    add_submenu_page(
        null, // Parent slug.
        'Quote Paid Request', // Page title.
        'Quote Paid Request', // Menu title.
        'manage_options', // Capabilities.
        'reply_paid_quotation', // Menu slug.
        'reply_paid_quotation' // Function.
    );
```

Данный код создаёт страницу, которой нет в меню, но она доступна по адресу

```
/wp-admin/admin.php?page=reply_paid_quotation
```